# Problems casting a uint8_t array to a struct

Tags: microcontroller, c

I'm having problems casting an array of uint8_t to a struct in C using a Silicon Labs MCU (EFM32GG11B120F2048GQ64).  The byte array is the received data from a UART, and I want to cast it to a struct representing the message structure.

When casting the array to the struct, `report_type` (uint8_t) is byte [0] in the array, as it should.  **But `start_time` (uint32_t) is not the value of bytes [1..4] as I would think, but rather bytes [4..7].  Bytes [1..3] are not used.**

I tried adding a second uint8_t member `report_type2`, effectively moving `start_time` down one position.  `report_type2` gets the value of byte [1], but `start_time` still gets the value of bytes [4..7].

Anybody knows what's going on here and **why this is**?

Byte array:

```
05 29 68 58 3C 0E 10 02 44 0D D5 C3 3F 0F 5C 29 00 05 69 75 00 00 0A B8 07 25 A7 11 00 B5 01 02 4C 1D 00 1C 0A FF FF 00 00 00 0A 01 B9 06 00 09 07 25 A7 11 00 B5 01 02 4C 1D 00 1C 0A FF FF 00 00 00 0A 01 B9 06 00 09 07 25 A7 11 00 B5 01 02 4C 1D 00 1C
```

Struct:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t report_type;
   uint32_t start_time;
   uint16_t period_length;
   uint8_t status_alarm_code;
   float_union_t total;
   float_union_t average;
   subperiod_t subperiod_1;
   subperiod_t subperiod_2;
   subperiod_t subperiod_3;
   subperiod_t subperiod_4;
   subperiod_t subperiod_5;
   subperiod_t subperiod_6;
   subperiod_t subperiod_7;
   subperiod_t subperiod_8;
   subperiod_t subperiod_9;
   subperiod_t subperiod_10;
}report_t;
```

Casting array to struct:

```
report_t *report = (report_t *)packet->data;
```

Comment: Please read about struct padding, packing, and serialization.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23495920/1401213) for starters.

Comment: try `typedef struct {...} __attribute__((packed)) report_t;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot do dirty casts like this in C. There are multiple problems:

- The data you copy from might not be aligned.
- The struct might have padding bytes to compensate for internal alignment that are not present in the data you copy from.
- Dereferencing this struct pointer after the cast leads to a [strict pointer aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), meaning it's undefined behavior bug which could result in incorrect machine code getting generated.

---

The safest and most portabile solution is write a function that does serialization/deserialization of the struct data. That is, a function writing to each member manually. This is slightly slower due to the overhead code but the most portable.

Less portable but probably faster is to `memcpy` the data. If you do this, you must be absolutely sure that the struct has no padding. Which you aren't, the struct you posted is very poorly designed by someone who has never heard of alignment, since it has padding gaps all over it. If you re-design the struct to ensure there's no padding, you could use `memcpy` or similar methods.

(Union type punning is yet another option.)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you are a beginner to intermediately skilled C programmer, you should pretty much _never_ use casts. This will save you from a ton of subtle bugs. When uncertain, ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think you hit the mark square on there.  I was actually planning on writing to each member manually as you suggested - I was just curious about why this was.  Where can I find more info on a well designed vs poorly designed struct?  I've Googled, but I can't identify what makes the struct I designed bad.  Isn't it OK if I'm writing to each member manually?

Comment: This is Cortex-M. Any GCC based compiler will support packed structs on it. It might be a trick but it can be done as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Oystein Assuming you are using something like Silabs EFM then it's 32 bit aligned. A compiler is explicitly not allowed to re-order the memory of struct members, it's one of the few ways C provides that guarantees how data is stored. Therefore you end up with `uint8_t report_type` 3 byte padding then `uint32_t start_time` and so on. These padding bytes are nothing but waste of space.

Comment: @Oystein Check out this x86 example: https://godbolt.org/z/b1cM5TsYv. Without the "FIX" it's your original code, the struct always starts at an aligned address. Then `report_type` takes up 4 bytes instead of 1. #define FIX and it does nothing but reorder the members so that there will be no padding gaps. And suddenly the struct takes up 8 bytes instead of 12.

Comment: @Justme Or in this case just re-order the struct members correctly since their allocation order doesn't seem to matter. No need to disable padding.

Comment: @Lundin Wow, thank you!  I see what you mean then.

Comment: Just for reference, ARM provides the CMSIS layer for Cortex processors, and it contains pre-defined macros to pack structures. For multiple different compiler as well. And ST provides similar macros for their MCUs. ARM and Keil even mention struct packing as one topic for writing optimized code. Under these circumstances, it would be quite hard to justify why struct packing is wrong and should not be done.

Comment: @Justme It's wrong in this specific case, since all it achieves is a pointless introduction of non-standard C features like `__attribute__` or `#pragma pack`. Reordering the members solves the problem. Using structs to represent data protocols and similar was always problematic in C. Alignment isn't the only concern, but also things like endianess, so there might be no way around writing the serialization/desearialization routines.

Comment: @Lundin In this case adding `__attribute__` as @Justme suggested worked fine and would be a quicker solution than manually setting each member in the struct.  However, I think setting the members was a safer and more readable approach, so I opted to spend the time to do that instead.

Comment: @Oystein Inspecting structs for alignment layout should be part of any peer code review audit. It's something I almost always have remarks about when reviewing. If you try to use structs to represent data protocols etc then it's another story and you are forced to use a fixed layout and disable padding. Which in turn, as previously mentioned, does not solve other problems like network endianess, requiring serialization/deserialization routines.

Comment: Regarding 'union type punning', this is an interesting read: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/04/using-pointers-to-recast-in-c-is-bad.html

Comment: @Seir It's basically the same thing as said in the SO post I linked. Apart from avoiding bugs related to strict aliasing, unions also have yet another exotic type punning feature called "common initial sequence". Which in turn apparently got diverse compiler support with different compilers reading the standard differently, resulting in some Defect Reports to the C committee. I'm not sure of the status of that feature with the new C standards.

Answer (score 8):

Struct elements may not be assumed contiguous for data alignment reasons.

It seems your compiler assumes alignment to 32 bits.

Depending on your compiler, there might be a way to make it pack the struct elements, exact mehtod can be found in the compiler manual.

Comment: Packing isn't likely a viable solution. Data is aligned for a reason.

Comment: @Lundin Maybe. The compiler should be smart enough to read unaligned variables as long as it knows they're unaligned.

Comment: @user253751 Depends on the ISA. I'm not sure what "Silicon Labs MCU" means, probably either a Cortex M or some old 8051 crap in which cases it should be ok, but maybe they got other ISA too.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, bad description on my part.  The MCU is EFM32GG11B120F2048GQ64.

Comment: @Justme Thank you for the tip!  While I'm sure you're correct, I think I will go for manually setting the struct members.  Just to improve readability, if nothing else..

Comment: Either way, disabling padding doesn't solve the strict aliasing violation. Don't write code with UB when it can be avoided. Especially not when gcc is the expected compiler, which I believe is the case at least in the disasterware known as "Siplicity Studio".